# Using bluebird Promise to catch all errors at once from many mongoose callback methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Initially, I had these two methods being implemented:

```
  User.update({id: req.body.myId}, {$addToSet: { FriendIds:       
 req.body.friendId}}, function(err, user){

 if (err) {

return res.status(404).send('Unable to start chat')

  }    

  User.update({id: req.body.friendId}, {$addToSet: { FriendIds:      
 req.body.myId}}, function(err, user){


  if (err) {
return res.status(404).send('Unable to start chat')

 }

 return res.send('Chat Initiated')    



 });


});
```

I was notified that promises in blue bird would be a better way to do all of this. So after further research,  I implemented it with blue bird like so:

```
  Promise.all([User.update({id: req.body.myId}, {$addToSet: {     FriendIds: req.body.friendId}}), User.update({id: req.body.friendId},                {$addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.myId}})  ])
  .then(function (results){

  console.log(results[0]);

  }).catch(function (err){

 console.log(err);

 });
```

There are two things concerning me with this code being a total newbie in bluebird. The first is that even though both update functions do get triggered, `console.log(results[0]);` gives me this:

{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }, this worries me as I thought that it would print out the user like it would in the first snippet of code. The second is that, does the catch method get triggered if one of the promises gets an error? Or even so, did i even implement it right? I could not find a proper example in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code looks ok.

The result `{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }` implies that the query ran fine, found 1 document (`n`) to match your query but it already contained the ID so wasn't updated (`nModified`). `addToSet` "Adds values to the array if not already present".

Any errors that occur inside the `all` promises will be caught, that includes both queries. Note that not updating a record is not an error. Nor is not finding a record for a query, so you do need to check for null / empty / negative results with mongodb/mongoose.

```
  Promise.all([
    User.update({id: req.body.myId}, {$addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.friendId}}).exec(),
    User.update({id: req.body.friendId}, {$addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.myId}}).exec()
  ])
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log(results[0]);
    console.log(results[1]);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send('Unable to start chat')
    // or next(err) if you use a global express error handler. 
  });
```

Comment: Just one more question actually, assuming there is an error in one of them, will anything in the "then" function get called as well as catch, or just whats in catch?

Comment: Only the `.catch` code will run if one of the promises is rejected or has an error. `.all` require all promises to resolve before `.then` will start.

Comment: Though as a side note, it is also possible to throw an error in the `.then` and that would finish immediately and also move onto `.catch` too.

Comment: Awesome, although it's quite puzzling how the mere Javascript Promise library is able to detect when a mongoose function throws an error and then catch it. I thought Promises only failed if there was a reject somewhere. Your thoughts on that?

Comment: bluebird voodoo... last I remember native Promises were trying to nail down the spec still. Maybe ask that as a follow up question as there's a few of the ppl who work on bluebird and are involved in the spec that actively answer on here and know way more about it than I do.